# GoodData and AWS S3 Integration

Tags: gooddata

I have two questions related to the situation, if I need to set up the GoodData-S3 Integration for all projects under a segment:

1. Will LCM help me to deploy the ADD Component across all the projects on that segment, OR do I need to deploy the ADD component separately on each of the project?
2. Do I need to specify the client_id for each project in the ADD Component, or will it use the client_id from the segment?

Answer (score 0):

*1) Will LCM help me to deploy the ADD Component across all the projects on that segment OR do I need to deploy the ADD component separately on each of the project?*

If you have multiple workspaces to load data to and you have the workspaces organized into segments (see Set Up Automated Data Distribution v2 for Object Storage), you only need to deploy the ADD v2 to the service workspace.

*2) Do I need to specify the client_id for each project in the ADD Component or will it use the client_id from the segment?*

You need to make sure that the source files that you want to distribute separately per workspace has the x__client_id column. This column should contain the values corresponding to the client ID values of your client workspaces so then it can be specified accordingly.